# limit problem (trouble with understanding simplification)

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit or explain why it does not exist:

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{4- 4x + x^2}}{x-2}$$

so I mean.. of course I had no chance to solve this other than plugging in for x, by ths method the limit doesn't exist, but anyway I decided to look in the solution manual and it says $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{4- 4x + x^2}}{x-2}$ = $\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$? and therefore it doesnt exist. (I know how to evaluate limits of absolute value so there is no problem for me to evaluate this and show that it doesn't exist).

My question is just how came thoose two expressions are equal?

Comment: Completing the square.

Comment: $\sqrt{(x-2)^{2}}=|x-2|$. Think about what happen when $x<2$ and when $x\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{4-4x+x^2}}{x-2}=\frac{\sqrt{(x-2)^2}}{x-2}=\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$$

I think the step you are confused about is $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=|x-2|$. This is because the square root function is defined to be the positive solution to $x^2=y$ given $y\ge0$. For example, take $x=1$, then $\sqrt{(x-2)^2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt1=1$, which is positive, while just taking $x-2=1-2=-1$ would be negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{4-4x+x^2} = \sqrt{(2-x)^2} = |2-x| = |x-2|$$

Comment: oh.. thanks man! :D